# How to find the default windows sdk version that a solution is using?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

Whenever I sync a solution from the place where it is hosted,and on building it, it says windows sdk 8.1 could not be found, the default windows sdk version should be 10.0.17134.0 . This is causing me some issues when the code is executed on a server. How do I check or change the default windows sdk version.

Comment: The project file is an XML which you can parse and edit.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're using visual studio; right-click on your solution->project then in the main tab 'Windows-SDK' 8.1 should be specified. Set this to your latest version.

Comment: Could you be more precise ?